# How to count the number of reviews in my files in a folder and then sort by highest to lowest?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

thanks anyone who has helped me so far, here is my problem: I have a folder which contains 825 files. Within these files are reviews of a hotel. An example name of one of these files is `hotel_72572.dat` and this file basically contains the following:

```
<Overall Rating>4
<Avg. Price>$173
<URL>http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60878-d72572-r23327047-Best_Western_Pioneer_Square_Hotel-Seattle_Washington.html

<Author>everywhereman2
<Content>Old seattle...
<Date>Jan 6, 2009
<img src="http://cdn.tripadvisor.com/img2/new.gif" alt="New"/>
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>5
<Value>5
<Rooms>5
<Location>5
<Cleanliness>5
<Check in / front desk>5
<Service>5
<Business service>5

<Author> //repeats the fields again, each cluster of fields is a review
```

The fields (line 6 - `<Business service>`) are then repeated by n times where n is the number of reviews in the file. I thought that by counting the number of times "Author" appears per file would achieve this but perhaps there is a better solution?

I am trying to write a script that will called countreviews.sh that will count the number of reviews per file in my folder (the folder name is reviews_folder) and then sort the number per file from highest to lowest. An example output will be:

```
hotel_72572 45
hotel_72579 33
hotel_73727 17
```

where the prefix is the name of the file and the number is the number of reviews per file. My script must take the folder name as an argument. For example I would type ./countreviews.sh reviews_folder and would get my output.

I have received lots of help over the past few days with many different suggestions but none of them have achieved what I am trying to do (my fault due to poor explanations), I hope this finally explains it clearly enough. Thanks again anyone who has helped me over the past few days and for any help I get for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -c Author hotel_*.dat | sort -t : -k2nr | sed 's/\.dat:/ /'
```

Output (e.g.):

```
hotel_72572 45
hotel_72579 33
hotel_73727 17
```

**Update**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1" || exit 1
grep -c Author hotel_*.dat | sort -t : -k2nr | sed 's/\.dat:/ /'
```

Comment: Thanks, my script must take the folder name "reviews_folder" as an argument in the command line e.g. ./countreviews.sh reviews_folder. Sorry I didn't mention this too many things to remember

Comment: My countreviews.sh script sits in the same directory as the folder containing the files of reviews